# How to update employee email address from employee table (need to change just domain name of all employees)

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have employee table with 100 records and have email-id column in it.
but suppose now company has changed domain of email id example:- earlier it was abc@example.com
now it has changed to abc@gmail.com

so how to update same in employees table only have to change domain name from email id of employee table

Please suggest some way in oracle plsql or sql

Comment: It is not necessary to SHOUT when asking a question here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING will not get you an answer any faster. It's also impolite to come here and SHOUT at us when you're asking us for free help to solve your problem. Please disable your CAPS lock when posting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE` as follows:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE
   SET EMAIL = REPLACE(EMAIL,'@example.com','@gmail.com')
```